# Category url appending -1 out of the blue

Tags: category, url, url-rewrite

As I know it, magento only ads a -1 when creating or editing a url that already exists, in order to not have duplicate urls.

But this time magento ads a -1 to categories out of the blue, without editing the categories. For example yesterday I checked all my categories in the menu, and none of them had links with -1, but today some of them have -1 in urls when checking the menu.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the url rewrite already exists, when the indexer checked it.

1. You created it yourself
2. a product uses the URL
3. a category uses the URL
4. another module created the URL

Comment: yeah, I suspect a module, because no one touched the categories and products have a very different url structure. Magento ads a -1 because there is already a rewrite redirect in place from category.html to category-1.html. Who does this rewrite, I don't know, but I suspect a module.

Comment: This happens, when magento thinks, that you renamed the category - don't ask me how this happens, no clue